# Glide doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I need to show in `recyclerview` images taken from server.

Images are fetched correctly from `server` but `glide` doesn't show me images, I don't know why.

I show you my code:

VIDEO:

```
public class Video {
    public String pic;
    public String sottotitolo;
    public String titolo;
    public String data;


    public Video() {
    }

    public Video(String pic,String sottotitolo,String titolo,String data){


        this.pic = pic;
        this.sottotitolo=sottotitolo;
        this.titolo=titolo;
        this.data=data;

    }

    public String getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(String pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }
    public String getSottotitolo() {
        return sottotitolo;
    }

    public void setSottotitolo(String sottotitolo) {
        this.sottotitolo = sottotitolo;
    }
    public String getTitolo() {
        return titolo;
    }

    public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
        this.titolo = titolo;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

ADAPTER:

```
public  class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Video> mData;
    private ArrayList<Video> mData2;


    private Activity mACtivity;

    public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> data,ArrayList<Video> data2,Activity activity) {
        this.mData = data;
        this.mData2 = data2;

        this.mACtivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anteprima_list_item, parent, false);
        return new VideoHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoHolder holder, int position) {
        Video video = mData.get(position);
        Video video2 = mData2.get(position);

        holder.setTitolo(video.getTitolo());
        holder.setSottoTitolo(video.getSottotitolo());

        holder.setData(video.getData());

        holder.setData(video.getData());


       /* holder.setAddress(restaurant.getAddress());
        holder.setCost("Average cost for 2: " + restaurant.getCurrency() + restaurant.getCost());
        holder.setRating(restaurant.getRating());*/

        Glide.with(mACtivity)
                .load(video2.getPic())
                .into(holder.restaurantImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mData == null)
            return 0;
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView restaurantImageView;
        TextView restaurantNameTextView;
        TextView restaurantAddressTextView;
        TextView restaurantRatingTextView;
        TextView costTextView;
        TextView distanceTextView;

        public VideoHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

             restaurantImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_restaurant);
            restaurantNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_restaurant_name);
            restaurantAddressTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_address_textview);
            distanceTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_distance_textview);

           /*  costTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_for_two_textview);

           restaurantRatingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);*/

        }

        public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
            restaurantNameTextView.setText(titolo);
        }

       public void setSottoTitolo(String sottotitolo) {
            restaurantAddressTextView.setText(sottotitolo);
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            distanceTextView.setText(data);
        }
      /*  public void setPic(String pic) {
            distanceTextView.setText(pic);
        }

         public void setCost(String cost) {
            costTextView.setText(cost);
        }

        public void setDistance(String distance) {
            distanceTextView.setText(distance);
        }*/
    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView videoRecyclerView;
    private VideoAdapter mAdapter;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    //private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON

    private static String url = "https://myapi.com";

    ArrayList<Video> videoList;
    ArrayList<Video> videoList2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        videoList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new VideoAdapter(videoList,videoList2, this);


        videoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        videoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        videoRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        videoRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        new GetContacts().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
           /* pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();*/

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        Video video=new Video();
                        String titolo = c.getString("titolo");
                        String sottotitolo = c.getString("sottotitolo");
                        String data = c.getString("date");
                        video.setTitolo(titolo);
                        video.setSottotitolo(sottotitolo);
                        video.setData(data);



                        videoList.add(video);
                    }


                    JSONArray img_url = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("output2");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for(int i=1;i<=11;i++)

                    {

                        String c = img_url.getString(i);

                        // Log.i("Value is:::",""+c);
                        System.out.println("C:"+c);

                        Video video=new Video();
                        videoList2.add(video);

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }    else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
       /*     if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();*/
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
          /*  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                    "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);*/
        }

    }


}
```

BUILD GRADLE:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.marco.ud2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

}
```

Comment: do you have INTERNET permission?

Comment: yes otherwise i wan not able to fetch title etc ecc

Comment: Are you getting the pic url from `video2.getPic()`? You are getting other information because you had set that data in your **MainActivity**, set your image or pic data too then check it again.